# Aluminum Pan Reuse

Tags: tevilas-keilim-dipping, halacha

If you reuse an Aluminium pan does it then require a Tevilah as it is no longer a one time use disposable pan and now is a Keli which requires Tevilah?

Answer (score 6):

Not according to [R' Moshe](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=254).  The pans that I have used do not last long.  If you don't cut a hole in them, the heat will eventually thin it out.

Answer (score 5):

According to R' Moshe Shternbuch, [T'Shuvot V'Hanhagot 3:259](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49820&pgnum=290) (mis-attributed in footnote 30 of [this document](http://download.yutorah.org/2010/Torah%20Perspectives%20on%20Recycling.doc) to 4:192), one is only exempt from immersing the vessel if he throws it out immediately after the first use. If one decides to use it more than once, or if the local custom is to use it more than once, it requires tevilah.

In [4:192](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20027&pgnum=190), he says that when using a disposable aluminum pan in a place where many people reuse them, before you use it the first time you should decide to use it twice and immerse it. See there for reasoning and details.

In general, there is an interesting discussion amongst the various commentaries about the halachic status of aluminum with regards to immersion. Since it is not mentioned in the torah as one of the 6 metals that require immersion, different Rabbis have different opinions about whether or not aluminum Biblically requires immersion, etc. See [here](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/chulin/insites/ch-dt-025.htm) for a nice breakdown (but please look up the sources yourself since he seems to have gotten R' Moshe Shternbuch position wrong in [1:451](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20025&pgnum=314)).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/weekly_torah.php?id=393

> Aluminum pans which are thrown out after use do not require
>   tevilla.(Horav Yisroel Belsky Shlita, see L'Torah V'horah 2:page 41,
>   Igros Moshe Y.D. 3:23, Kinyan Torah 1:51:1, Oz Nedberu 7:71, Minchas
>   Yitzchok 5:32, Yeishiv Moshe 1:111, Teshuvos V'hanhugos 3:259, Shraga
>   Hameir 2:83, Minchas Osher Y.D. 2:5, Divrei Chachumim page 189:37,
>   Shalmei Moed page 515, Pischei Halacha Kashrus (Hebrew) page 60:20,
>   Tevilas Keilim 1:7:footnote 10, 11:148, Chelkes Binyomin Y.D. 120:69)
>
> One who wants to use an aluminum pan more than once does not need to
>   tovel it because the Yid is the one who is making the pan into a
>   permanent utensil.(Horav Yisroel Belsky Shlita, see Chelkes Binyomin
>   ibid.)
>
> The Star-K holds an aluminum pan used more than once requires tevila
>   with a beracha.

Comment: Interesting twist on the subject by R' Belsky. But of what consequence is it that the Jew is the one who made the decision to reuse it? The object itself was not made by him. http://revach.net/ask/article.php?id=34 (The linked article is not directly related; it addresses Ma'aseh Uman, and I don't know how deciding to reuse it changes the item.)

Comment: Although [this is an interesting counterpoint](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7031/5).

Comment: The one who made it, made it with the intention of one time use. And the Jew who uses it more than once is making it into a permanent vessel.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to bee Anon's argument as well. I would love to see a source supporting that, because otherwise all I've got to go on are the Halachoth I'm familiar with, which are that final assembly is what matters.

Comment: Well the source is Rabbi Belsky and the Chelkas Binyamin.

Comment: OK, fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

According to R. Obhadia Yosef ([as cited here](https://halachayomit.co.il/he/Default.aspx?HalachaID=633&PageIndex=2)) disposable aluminum vessels require immersion (irrespective of whether it is resused), however it should be done without a blessing.

According to R. Bension Musafi ([as cited here](https://www.doresh-tzion.co.il/QASearchResult.aspx?qa=cat%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%95%D7%9F:%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%AA%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D)) disposable aluminum vessels do not require immersion, even when used more than once.

According to R. Abadi ([see here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=54963&st=&pgnum=204&hilite=)) whether a disposable aluminum vessel requires immersion depends on intent - if you intend to use it more than once, it should be immersed.

Answer (score 1):

A jews decision to use something as a vessel does not create a requirement of tevillah. Assuming that the pan didn't originally need tevillah the later decision adds no requirement.

Comment: your souce for this is?

Comment: It's true and not true... so a source would be beneficial.  If I decide to use a metal suitcase as a plate for my food, it doesn't require tevila. But deciding if something is disposable or not, does.